# How does a server browser e.g. in games work?

Tags: java, networking, broadcast

I have written a variety of network programmes such as chats and games, but the user always had to enter the ip of the server, which is very unusual.
I want to realize a server browser you may know from common games, which locates servers in the lan automatically. I want to do it in Java.

My questions are:

How does that browsing work? Also WiFi for example, just everything which automatically finds another party.

Would it be possible and also a good approach to broadcast status packages to whole lan all the time? Which time intervals would be useful?

Comment: For the internet server list, I would think that the game company probably has a configured well-known entry point server where they can discover other available servers.

Comment: I'd imagine a game server listens on a specific port for incoming connections.  So a simple scan of that port (or range of ports) on the host's current subnet should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

For WiFi, the device listens to a certain frequency range and scans the range for signals. This is much the same process as a TV uses to pick-up stations, or a person might do to find local radio stations.

For an internet game server, you can't scan the entire internet. Normally the services provides a master server which is configured to send the list of servers on a known port. Typically it will also allow servers to update their information as well.

For a local game server, typically it's single packet every few seconds or so. There's actually quite a lot of traffic even on an idle network with various services requesting this sort of data (Apple's discovery protocol, Bonjour is commonly seen, as is the Windows network discovery protocol).

Comment: WiFi: Does the client who is looking for networks listen on the frequency or the access point?

Comment: Clients scan frequencies for the SSID which is broadcasted by the access point.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse, This is wrong.  Scanning for wireless networks is not simply changing the channel and listening.  Your computer sends out probe frames for the networks it knows about as it tries to find which networks are available.  APs generally send beacon packets, but they are not required to.  Many people shut these off so that the person has to know the SSID of the network to join it.  (Although that isn't perfect, as you can just listen for probe packets and figure out what networks might be around.)

Comment: @Brad So assuming no-one broadcasts the SSID it's listening on each channel for probe packets.... aka scanning the different channels for traffic... which is fundamentally what I wrote.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse, No, the client transmits probe packets, and it is up to the AP to respond to them.  The only thing that *should* be listening for probe packets is an AP, or ad-hoc clients.

Answer (score 0):

For internet games, there is a central set of servers that host the information needed to a set up a game.  In the past, this is typically just the IP address and port of the person hosting the game, as well as any game information, such as the name, map, etc.

These days due to firewall/NAT issues and problems with cheating, most internet games actually send their data through those servers as well.  This is expensive to do.

For games on your local network, UDP packets are sent to the broadcast address, which are received by all devices on that subnet.  The hosting game sends the packet with information on where to connect, and those joining in receive those packets to know where the game server is.  They then connect directly to the game server.

If you are on an IP network and your address is 192.168.1.100 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0, then your broadcast IP address is 192.168.1.255.  See also:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address#IP_networking